# Performance of UDAF versus Aggregator in Spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to write some performance-mindful code in Spark and wondering whether I should write an [Aggregator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/Aggregator.html) or a [User-defined Aggregate Function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html) (UDAF) for my rollup operations on a Dataframe.

I have not been able to find any data anywhere on how fast each of these methods are and which you should be using for spark 2.0+.

Comment: What _"rollup operations"_ are you thinking about? `rollup` aggregation is supported in Spark SQL already.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Hi Jacek, that's what I mean, using `rollup` but with a custom aggregation function.

Answer (score 1):

You should write an `Aggregator` rather than an `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` as [`UserDefinedAggregateFunction` performs  inefficient serialization/deserialization tasks for each row](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27296). Rewriting an `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` to an `Aggregator` can improve performance from 25%-30% to 100x, as stated [in pull request replacing `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` with `Aggregator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/25024#issue-293548866)

Due to those performance issues, [`UserDefinedAggregateFunction` class has been deprecated in Spark 3.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30423)