# spark: What is the difference between Aggregator and UDAF？

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

In Spark's documentation, Aggregator:

> abstract class Aggregator[-IN, BUF, OUT] extends Serializable
>
> A base class for user-defined aggregations, which can be
> used in Dataset operations to take all of the elements of a group and
> reduce them to a single value.

UserDefinedAggregateFunction is:

> abstract class UserDefinedAggregateFunction extends Serializable
>
> The base class for implementing user-defined aggregate functions
> (UDAF).

According to [Dataset Aggregator - Databricks](http://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Dataset%20Aggregator.html), “an Aggregator is similar to a UDAF, but the interface is expressed in terms of JVM objects instead of as a Row .”

It seems these two classes are very similar, what are other differences apart from the types in the interface?

A similar question is: [Performance of UDAF versus Aggregator in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356452/performance-of-udaf-versus-aggregator-in-spark)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fundamental difference, apart from types, is external interface:

- `Aggregator` takes a complete `Row` (it is intended for "strongly" typed API).
- `UserDefinedAggregationFunction` takes a set of `Columns`.

This makes `Aggregator` less flexible, although overall API is far more user friendly.

There is also a difference with handling state:

- `Aggregator` is stateful. Depends on mutable internal state of its buffer field.
- `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` is stateless. State of the buffer is external.