# Spark UDAF: How to get value from input by column field name in UDAF (User-Defined Aggregation Function)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate, user-defined-aggregate

I am trying to use Spark UDAF to summarize two existing columns into a new column. Most of the tutorials on Spark UDAF out there use indices to get the values in each column of the input Row. Like this:

```
input.getAs[String](1)
```

, which is used in my update method (`override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit`). It works in my case as well. However I want to use the field name of the that column to get that value.  Like this:

```
input.getAs[String](ColumnNames.BehaviorType)
```

, where ColumnNames.BehaviorType is a String object defined in an object:

```
 /**
    * Column names in the original dataset
    */
  object ColumnNames {
    val JobSeekerID = "JobSeekerID"
    val JobID = "JobID"
    val Date = "Date"
    val BehaviorType = "BehaviorType"
  }
```

This time it does not work. I got the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "BehaviorType" does not
>   exist.    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:292)
>   ... at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAs(Row.scala:333)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getAs(rows.scala:165)
>     at
>   com.recsys.UserBehaviorRecordsUDAF.update(UserBehaviorRecordsUDAF.scala:44)

Some relevant code segments：

This is part of my UDAF:

```
class UserBehaviorRecordsUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {


  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("JobID", IntegerType) ::
      StructField("BehaviorType", StringType) :: Nil)

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    println(input.schema.treeString)
    println
    println(input.mkString(","))
    println
    println(this.inputSchema.treeString)
//    println
//    println(bufferSchema.treeString)

    input.getAs[String](ColumnNames.BehaviorType) match { //ColumnNames.BehaviorType //1 //TODO WHY??
      case BehaviourTypes.viewed_job =>
        buffer(0) =
          buffer.getAs[Seq[Int]](0) :+ //Array[Int]  //TODO WHY??
          input.getAs[Int](0) //ColumnNames.JobID
      case BehaviourTypes.bookmarked_job =>
        buffer(1) =
          buffer.getAs[Seq[Int]](1) :+ //Array[Int]
            input.getAs[Int](0)//ColumnNames.JobID
      case BehaviourTypes.applied_job =>
        buffer(2) =
          buffer.getAs[Seq[Int]](2) :+  //Array[Int]
            input.getAs[Int](0) //ColumnNames.JobID
    }
  }
```

The following is the part of codes that call the UDAF:

```
val ubrUDAF = new UserBehaviorRecordsUDAF

val userProfileDF = userBehaviorDS
  .groupBy(ColumnNames.JobSeekerID)
  .agg(
    ubrUDAF(
      userBehaviorDS.col(ColumnNames.JobID), //userBehaviorDS.col(ColumnNames.JobID)
      userBehaviorDS.col(ColumnNames.BehaviorType) //userBehaviorDS.col(ColumnNames.BehaviorType)
    ).as("profile str"))
```

It seems the field names in the schema of the input Row are not passed into the UDAF:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
root
 |-- input0: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- input1: string (nullable = true)


30917,viewed_job

root
 |-- JobID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- BehaviorType: string (nullable = true)
```

What is the problem in my codes?

Comment: UADF are supposed to be generic functions which can be used with any `DateSet` given that it satisfies the UADF requirements. Examples of UADF are `count`, `avg` etc. You do not define a UADF to be used with a single dataset and that is why UADF are not designed to support column names. Also the `row` in `update` is not actual `row` of the dataset but only the part passed to the UADF. For example if you do `avg(num_users)` for any dataset which has a column called `num_users` then the `row` in update function will only have 1 column and that is `num_users` column of original dataset row.

Comment: But I have already defined the inputSchema in the UDAF:
  `override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("JobID", IntegerType) ::
      StructField("BehaviorType", StringType) :: Nil)`
Is there a reference for "the row in update is not actual row of the dataset but only the part passed to the UADF."? Thanks!

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领 Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @IvanBalashov I used `Aggregator` instead of UDAF. `Aggregator` is strongly typed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180598/spark-what-is-the-difference-between-aggregator-and-udaf

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领 Indeed, will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also want to use the field names from my inputSchema in my update method to create maintainable code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
class MyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    val inputWSchema = new GenericRowWithSchema(input.toSeq.toArray, inputSchema)
```

Ultimately switched to Aggregator which ran in half the time.